# android - what happen in fragment onDetach

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am using nested fragments in the bottom navigation. at the first time, all fragments were loaded and everything is fine but when I changed the fragment, null exception fired and I saw that `getParentFragment()` return null since `onDetach` get called I need to know that in child fragment what happens in that func? child fragment gets detach from its parent and I have to set it again? how to avoid this detaching?

```
public void switchFrag() {

        Fragment displayedFragment;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (isListFragmentDisplayed) {
            displayedFragment = mapFragment;
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_contaner, displayedFragment, "map").commit();
        } else {
            displayedFragment = listFragment;
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_contaner, displayedFragment, "list").commit();

        }

        isListFragmentDisplayed = !isListFragmentDisplayed;
    }
```

Comment: please write your fragment change method

Answer (score 0):

The detach method removes the fragment from the UI, but its state is maintained by the Fragment Manager. This means you can reuse this fragment by calling the attach method, with a modified ViewHierarchy

Answer (score 0):

**Nested fragments are supported as of Android 4.2.**

you can use getChildFragmentManager() ...

Detach:

> Detach the given fragment from the UI. This is the same state as when
>   it is put on the back stack: the fragment is removed from the UI,
>   however its state is still being actively managed by the fragment
>   manager. When going into this state its view hierarchy is destroyed.